# Getting rows from SQLite as lists in a list

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I have problems with getting the data from a SQLAlchemy database. I need the rows of the database as lists and all of them go together in a list. Needed format:

```
list_of_lists = [[value_of_row1_column1, value_of_row1_column2], 
            [value_of_row2_column1, value_of_row2_column2]]
```

main.py:

```
    #list_sellers_format_needed = [[13.30570, 51.27430, "string1"], [13.30571, 52.27429, "string2"], [13.30565, 53.27436, "string3"]]
    list_sellers_db = Seller.query.all()
    final_list = []
    for i in list_sellers_db:
        final_list.append([i])
    print(final_list)
```

output Terminal:

```
    a list of lists in the format above
```

Comment: And what code have you tried?  All of the SQL connector cursors, including SQLite, return a list of tuples, exactly as you say.  What else could they do?

Comment: You got documentation about this? FInd it as beginner in sql very hard to understand what you mean... I got very big code... well its a database the 3 columns and x rows. Now I want to have all rows as lists inside a list.

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy methods like `.all()` return a list of `Row` objects. You can convert a `Row` object to a list by simply passing it to `list()`:

```py
qry = """\
SELECT 1 AS x, 'foo' AS y
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 AS x, 'bar' AS y
"""
with engine.begin() as conn:
    results = conn.exec_driver_sql(qry).all()
    list_of_lists = [list(row) for row in results]
    print(list_of_lists)
    # [[1, 'foo'], [2, 'bar']]
```

Comment: I get this error: "AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.engine' has no attribute 'begin'"

Comment: I just included your answer in my code above. Did I integrate it correctly?

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using? This answer is for version 1.4+.

Comment: Hey Gord, you see the code above I updated it correctly with your answer? I got 1.4.35

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution finally. I will integrate it in the answer above:

list_sellers_db = Seller.query.all()
final_list = []
for i in list_sellers_db:
final_list.append([i])

print(final_list)

will do the job.

But still I have the same issue. Coming through flask sqlalchemy it is ginving me an error:

raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**}
TypeError: Object of type Seller is not JSON serializable